# Example of primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am looking for an example of a primary decomposition of an ideal in a commutative noetherian ring, that isn't an UFD nor a dedekind domain and where the primary ideals in the decomposition is not equal to there radical ideals. That is, a good example on how to use the theory of existence and uniqueness of primary decomposition in Noetherian rings.

Comment: -navigetor23. The examples given in Atiyah and MacDonald (section 4 about Primary decomposition) concerns the ring $K[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$, for $K$ a field and various $n>0$. This is a UFD, so no, there is no such examples given there.

Comment: @harajm, some examples are about quotients of polynomial rings, i.e. it's not UFD/Dedekind at all.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834673/decomposition-of-i-x2-y2-xy#834673