# Primary decomposition of $I = (x^2, y^2, xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

> I want to find a primary decomposition of the ideal $$ I = (x^2,y^2,xy) \subset k[x,y]$$
>   where $k$ is a field.

How to proceed? Are there algorithms to find such decompositions? Where can I find them?

Comment: In fact this ideal is already primary, being a power of the maximal ideal $(x,y)$

Comment: zcn is right, but for algorithm and the use of it i wrote the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, there are algorithms to find such decompositions in the book "*Monomial Ideals*"  by "*Jürgen Herzog*-*Takayuki Hibi*":

[image]

(I deleted the proof of uniqueness)

[image]

[image]

[image]

so

> $I = (x^2, y^2, xy)=  ( y^2, x) \cap  (x^2, y)$

Comment: As it was mentioned under the question $I$ is already primary.