# Confusion on Monomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Definition:** An ideal is said to be *monomial ideal* if it is generated by monomials.   For example, in $k[x, y]$ $(xy, y^2)$ is a monomial ideal.

**Result:** Let $I$ be a monomial ideal with a generator $ab$ (where $a$ and $b$ are coprime), say 
$I= (ab) +J$, then $ I= ((a) +J) \cap ((b) +J))$.

Hence $ (xy, y^2) =(x, y^2) \cap (y, y^2) $ by the above rule as $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

**My questions:**

1) What is $J$ in the result?

2) In the example which I have given, who are $a,b$ and $J$?

- I have seen this in math. Stackexchange which I don't understand that is why I posted it.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you seen it at MSE? I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834673/primary-decomposition-of-i-x2-y2-xy), which is a bit different.

Comment: I have seen in another. I read your link now. But stumble because I don't know the term " Pure power" . Can you tell me this please

Comment: A pure power of the variable $x$ is given by $x^k$ for some positive integer $k$.  If you have two variables $x,y$ then $x^k$ and $y^j$ are pure powers, but $xy$ is not. What is your "another link" at mathematics stack exchange?

Comment: Then what is the difference between power and pure power? I don't know how to share a link in MSE, Sorry

Comment: $(xy)^2$ is a power in the variables $x,y$ but not a pure power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the Result $J$ denotes an ideal generated by $a^n$ or by $b^n$ for some positive integer $n$.

2) In your example $a=x,b=y$ and $J=(y^2)$, i.e, $J$ is the ideal generated by $y^2$. Thus, since $I=(xy,y^2)=(xy)+(y^2)$, by your Result you have

$$I=(xy,y^2)=(xy)+(y^2)=(\overbrace{(x)+(y^2)}^{(x,y^2)})\cap(\overbrace{(y)+(y^2)}^{(y,y^2)=(y)}).$$